# Angular 5 HttpClient POST request empty after successful CORS handshake

Tags: node.js, ajax, angular, http, cors

I'm new to the world of JavaScript and have been struggling with making AJAX requests from Angular to a back-end Node.js Express application. My POST request in my TypeScript file looks like this, with a JSON body:

```
    this.httpClient.post(url, createdOrUpdatedBlog, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}})
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.router.navigate(['/admin/blogs/list']);
    },
    error => console.log(error));
```

In my Node application I have some simple middleware to deal with CORS.

```
    app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',   'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
       res.send(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
```

I can see the OPTIONS request and an OK response is returned. I can also see the POST but it's always empty(no headers or content) and I can't figure out why.

[image: Successful OPTIONS request]
[image: Empty POST]

THere's probably something incredibly obvious I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the service is hanging and not returning a response.  It could be an issue with your express configuration for your API.

Comment: I can make the request using Postman without any problem so it looks like the API is configured properly. The payload definitely isn't empty.

Comment: can you share your express API code?

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using HttpClient, could you try setting your headers this way ?

```
{ headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8') }
```

as for your payload, check if you're not sending an empty one.

(I can't see the images because of my work proxy, is it in your chrome console or in your Node logs ?)

Comment: Setting the headers that way shouldnt make a difference. Downvoted as this doesnt attempt to solve OPs problem

Comment: Since it is a class, has several methods and properties, and is internal to Angular, I'm pretty sure that using it can make a difference rahter than using a plain object. Downvote all you want, but this is a solution to explore.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L358 internally a plain object would be transformed to a httpheaders instance. Again, your change in OPs code makes no difference.

Comment: I see, in this case my bad, thank you for the link !

Comment: I use interceptors for http headers. I took it from **[the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#configuring-other-parts-of-the-request)**, hence my answer

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be nothing to do with CORS and was because of an upper/lower case discrepancy between the front and back end...

Thanks anyway!